# How do I find which column is being declared incorrectly?

Tags: 2010, custom-list, site-template

I am a junior dev working on a Sharepoint 2007 to 2010 migration and am hitting the following error when I attempt to import the template:

The formula refers to a column that does not exist. Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing column.

Now this template is rife with customizations and after 2 weeks of investigation by myself and the senior dev, we are yet to find the offending column/s. I wish to know if there is a definitive way to find out which column is causing us grief? The error log (which I have set to pipe everything from verbose upwards) does not seem to be providing me the required information only that "The formula refers to a column that does not exist"

Comment: Check your formula for calculated column